# Reusing ant-snippets in multi-module maven build

Tags: maven, ant

How can I reuse an ant snippet in multiple projects? Lets say I have the following in my root `pom.xml`:

```
<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>gen-index</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
                <target>
                    ... some non-trivial ant stuff here ...
                </target>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        <execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

How can I have this ant snippet executed for selected sub-projects? I've tried adding the `<plugin>...</plugin>` part above to `<pluginManagement>...`, but I can't figure out how to specify for which sub-projects the ant snippet should be run.

Comment: So you need the same plugin execution in projects which are a sub-module and declare the above pom as parent?

Comment: Yes, something like that.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How do I execute simple ant call through maven?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480606/how-do-i-execute-simple-ant-call-through-maven)

Comment: No, this is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8480606/how-do-i-execute-simple-ant-call-through-maven. That question is how to invoke ant with certain parameters, this question is about how to reuse the same ant invocation in different places in the pom hierarchy.

Comment: There is a simple way. Write your parameters into a properties file and read this file in your ant script.

Answer (score 3):

i assume that your plugin definition with your target implementation is inside a pluginManagement section of a parent pom.xml

your ant target is inside a execution identified by "gen-index". it should be work if you declare some thing like this in your child project (but this time not inside a pluginManagement section...!!!):

```
<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>gen-index</id>
                <execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

this executes the target inherited by the parent pom with the same identifiert.

i hope this works four you. i used this several times like this..

with this constellation you could have more than one  inside the same plugin in your parent pom.xml.

I have created a GitHub repository with a working example: https://github.com/StefanHeimberg/stackoverflow-16056194