# Including another xml file in pom.xml

Tags: xml, maven

I am trying to include xml file in **`pom.xml (maven)`** . 
    My **`pom.xml`** looks somehting likes this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project>
<!-- <xi:include href="minify.xml" xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2003/XInclude"/>
 -->  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>myproject</groupId>
  <artifactId>myproject</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <description></description>
  <build>
    <plugins>

      <plugin>
        <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.2</version>
        <configuration>
          <source>1.5</source>
          <target>1.5</target>
        </configuration>
      </plugin>
    <!-- include plugin tag from other xml file -->
// I would like maintain one seperate xml file to hold all plugin tags (to reduce pom.xml //file content.
</plugins>
```

I am using **`"com.samaxes.maven"`** to **`minify css and js files`** . 
But I have kept my css and js files in many seperate folders . I need to include this below tag repeatedly

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
    <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.7.4</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-minify-1</id>
            <configuration>
                   <charset>utf-8</charset>
                   <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                   <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                   <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                  <!--   <skipMinify>true</skipMinify>   -->   <!--skips already minfied css fiels -->

                    <cssSourceDir>inc/one/css</cssSourceDir>
                   <cssTargetDir>inc/one/css/mini</cssTargetDir>
                   <cssSourceIncludes>
                      <cssSourceInclude>*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                   </cssSourceIncludes>

                    <jsSourceDir>proj/platform/common/js/</jsSourceDir>
                   <jsTargetDir>proj/platform/common/js/mini</jsTargetDir>
                   <jsSourceIncludes>
                     <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                   </jsSourceIncludes>
                   <closureCreateSourceMap>true</closureCreateSourceMap>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>minify</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
 </plugin>
```

I googled possible way to include multiple directories ,then I decided to include all directories by repeating above snippet code . But later though to separate all mifiy include to other xml file . I am looking some way to include xml file inside  tag . 
Some one please help me out.

Answer (score 1):

Another way of doing this is to use the iterator maven plugin. It has an ability to [iterate over folders](https://khmarbaise.github.io/iterator-maven-plugin/iterator-folder.html) and invoke another plugin for each item.

For your scenario, it would be something like

```
<plugin>
  <groupId>com.soebes.maven.plugins</groupId>
  <artifactId>iterator-maven-plugin</artifactId>
  <version>0.5.1</version>
  <executions>
    <execution>
      <phase>package</phase>
      <goals>
        <goal>iterator</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
        <folder>whatever/your/folder/is</folder>
        <pluginExecutors>
          <pluginExecutor>
            <plugin>
              <groupId>com.samaxes.maven</groupId>
              <artifactId>minify-maven-plugin</artifactId>
              <version>1.7.4</version>
            </plugin>
            <goal>minify</goal>
            <executions>
              <execution>
                <id>default-minify-1</id>
                <configuration>
                  <charset>utf-8</charset>
                  <jsEngine>CLOSURE</jsEngine>
                  <skipMerge>true</skipMerge>
                  <nosuffix>true</nosuffix>
                  <!--   <skipMinify>true</skipMinify>   -->   <!--skips already minfied css fiels -->

                  <cssSourceDir>@item@/inc/one/css</cssSourceDir>
                  <cssTargetDir>@item@/inc/one/css/mini</cssTargetDir>
                  <cssSourceIncludes>
                    <cssSourceInclude>*.css</cssSourceInclude>
                  </cssSourceIncludes>

                  <jsSourceDir>@item@/proj/platform/common/js/</jsSourceDir>
                  <jsTargetDir>@item@/proj/platform/common/js/mini</jsTargetDir>
                  <jsSourceIncludes>
                    <jsSourceInclude>*.js</jsSourceInclude>
                  </jsSourceIncludes>
                  <closureCreateSourceMap>true</closureCreateSourceMap>
                </configuration>
              </execution>
            </executions>
          </pluginExecutor>
        </pluginExecutors>
      </configuration>
    </execution>
  </executions>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

i think this is not the way maven should be used..

what you could do is to create a parent pom.xml with all the global plugin configuration inside a pluginManagement section. then you could activate your configured execution with id "default-minify-1" in all your child pom.xml. the but configuration is done only one time in the parent pom.xml

see [Reusing ant-snippets in multi-module maven build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16056194/reusing-ant-snippets-in-multi-module-maven-build/27869461#27869461)

Comment: Thank you @StefanHeimberg . Now I am using YUI compressor which solved my problem .